# Mocking Selenium responses in order to test UI controller

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, mocking

I'm using the Selenium interface in order to drive a UI, so as to have a programmatic API for something that's currently only a web UI. I'd like to write unit tests for this selenium-based application. How do I mock out calls to the original Selenium API in order to verify that the app is correct?

Here's a minimum example of the Selenium app:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def run_app(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
        assert "Google" in driver.title
        self.driver.close()
        return driver.title

def main():
    test_class = MyClass()
    results = test_class.run_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```